# Finding marginal PDF of the following

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose $(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4) \sim \text{Dir} (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4 ; \alpha_5)$, the Dirichlet distribution.

What is the marginal PDF of $(X_i, X_j) \ ; \ i \neq j$?

I have no idea how to do this one.
Please help.

Comment: Here is the case where you're trying to find the marginal PDF of only one of the random variables: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319292/find-marginal-distribution-of-k-variate-dirichlet. Hopefully this helps in the case of two random variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Note that

$$
(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)\stackrel{d}{=}\frac{(Z_1,Z_2,Z_3,Z_4)}{Z_1+Z_2+\dotsb+Z_5}
$$
where $Z_i$ are independent $\text{Gamma}(\alpha_i,1)$ random variables. In particular for example
$$
(X_1,X_2)\stackrel{d}{=}\frac{(Z_1,Z_2)}{Z_1+Z_2+(Z_3+\dotsb+Z_5)}
$$
sot that $(X_1,X_2)\sim\text{Dir}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2;\alpha_3+\alpha_4+\alpha_5)$. This should help you motivate the general solution supposing that you know the pdf corresponding to a Dirichlet Distribution.

Comment: What do you mean by $\stackrel{d}{=}$?

Comment: Equal in Distribution